# How to create a scatter plot from a text file Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with two columns and I want to create a scatter plot from it. I am new to Matlab so I am still learning the basics.

I tried using the load function and loading the text file into a variable.

```
average = load("averageAnalyze.txt")
scatter(average)
```

This is how my data looks from the text file like:

```
20  0.91
20  0.91
20  0.93
30  0.54
30  0.69
30  0.68
```

I want the x-axis to correspond to 20 and 30. I want the y axis to correspond with the numbers decimals you see on the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of MATLAB.

To plot 2-D scatter, it is as simple as `scatter(x,y)`. In your case:

```
average = load("averageAnalyze.txt");
scatter(1:numel(average), average);
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to control the visual effects (such as colour, size, etc.) of each individual simply use `plot`:

```
plot(average);
```

You can find more information here:

- [scatter](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)
- [plot](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?s_tid=doc_ta)

Also a pro tip: start using the documentation website :).